# VBScript Copy same file with adding second in Timestamp

Tags: vbscript, timestamp, file-copying

I want to copy same file 10000 times with timestamp change using VB Script. Original File name is MyFile.txt. So it will be copied like MyFile_20100131010000.txt. Second time file should be copied with name MyFile_20100131010001.txt.And so on like MyFile_20100131021003.txt. I am using below code snippet. But not sure how to convert DateAdd("s",intCount,"31-Jan-10 08:50:00") to timestamp.
e.g

```
For intCount = 1 to 10000   
     strDate = DateAdd("s",intCount,"31-Jan-10 08:50:00") 
     strNewName = objFSO.GetBaseName(objSourceFile) & "_" & strDate & "." & objFSO.GetExtensionName(objSourceFile)
    'CopyFile(strNewName)
Next
```

Please advise.

Comment: Does the Format function exist in VBScript? In VBA, I'd use something like `strFile = strFileBaseName & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMddhhmmssss" `

Comment: yeah. I want something formating function like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is slightly easier in VBA, as intimated in my comment, but it's not that tricky in VBScript either.

The function you're after is the `DatePart` one. It has a bunch of arguments that you're using that can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198903.aspx).

To generate a year-month-day-hour-minute-second timestamp using it, you basically concatenate a lot of those arguments together. Just in case there's a tick between seconds between function executions, it's worth assigning dtNow beforehand:

```
Dim dtNow
Dim i
Dim strDatePart

For i = 0 to 10000
    dtNow = DateAdd("s",i,"31-Jan-10 08:50:00")
    strDatePart = DatePart("yyyy", dtNow) & DatePart("m", dtNow) & DatePart("d", dtNow) & DatePart("h", dtNow) & DatePart( "n", dtNow) & DatePart("s", dtNow)
    '' Save your file here
Next
```